# How can I cover a rounded window under a slanted ceiling?

Tags: windows

We're soon moving into a new house, and my room has a big window (with a door  in it to access the balcony) under a slanted ceiling. The ceiling is quite steep, and there is very little clearing between it and the window.

I'm easily disturbed by light in my room when I'm trying to sleep, so I'm looking for a way to cover as much of the glass as possible with a material that lets very little light through.

Currently there are some very ugly curtains suspended to the ceiling, which you can pull away to the side and keep there with a tie-back. However, I'd prefer another type of covering. My desk is in the same room, so I'd want something that can let light through during the day (blinds for example, or perhaps two types of covering).

I've been thinking about it for a while, but I can't really find a solution to the problem. I'm not exactly up to date on what types of covering exist.

The illustration I added is not exactly to scale, but I think it captures the layout of that wall well enough. If accurate measurements or more info is needed, I'll be sure to add it.

[image: The wall]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Elegant and effective, high quality shutters block most light. They can be built with battery powered motors for remote control opening and closing. Must be custom made for most circumstances like yours, so not the cheapest option.

[image]

Blinds would be a nice option. Also must be custom made but a bit cheaper than shutters.